Trying to set ILogger<>.BeginScope with properties but is not working
I'm trying to set properties and see them in all my logs, but can't make it work.
Starting with a simple example, where I would like to see only 1 log with attached properties but nothing. I can see the structured logging property but not the attached state to the scope.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder
    .Services
    .AddLogging(c => c.AddJsonConsole(y => y.JsonWriterOptions = new() { Indented = true }));

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", async (ILogger<Program> logger) =>
    {
        var state = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "CustPropOne", "123456-7890123" },
            { "CustPropTwo", "blah blah blah" },
            { "CustNumber", 12345 }
        };
        using (logger.BeginScope(state))
        {
            logger.LogInformation("API 1 {One}", 1);

            var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
                    new WeatherForecast
                    (
                        DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                        Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                        summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                    ))
                .ToArray();
            return forecast;
        }
    })
    .WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
    .WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}

I was expecting to see in the state all the custom properties added to the dictionary.
The log I see on the formatted console:
{
  "EventId": 0,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Category": "Program",
  "Message": "API 1 1",
  "State": {
    "Message": "API 1 1",
    "Uno": 1,
    "{OriginalFormat}": "API 1 {Uno}"
  }
}


What is being logged?

@PMF updated the question with the output
